# Java Nashorn engine ArrayNode handling

Tags: java, nashorn

I use the *Java Nashorn engine* to execute Javascript code. I use the `eval` method of the `ScriptEngine object` which has a second parameter for "bindings". I use this to pass variables to the engine. It works fine with Object type and with primitive wrapper classes, but when I try to pass an ArrayNode it does not work as a JavaScript array and I have no idea why.

Example code:

```
String scriptText = "myarray[1] = 666";
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();
array.add(1);
array.add(2);
array.add(3);

bindings.put("myarray", arrayNode);
engine.eval(scriptText, bindings);
```

This should change the myarray value in the bindings object, but it does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nashorn supports script array-like indexed access/update on

1. Java Array objects
2. java.util.ArrayList objects
3. jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject objects

If ArrayNode is not an ArrayList subtype, you can implement JSObject interface in ArrayNode class or wrap ArrayNode with a JSObject implementation & expose that to script ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/JSObject.html ).

An example demonstrating the three cases mentioned above:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.script.*;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");

    // Java array accessed by indexing
    String[] arr = { "hello", "world" };
    e.put("jarr", arr);
    e.eval("jarr[1] = jarr[1].toUpperCase()"); // change first element
    System.out.println(arr[1]); // change reflected here

    // Java ArrayList accessed by indexing
    ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<>();
    alist.add("nashorn");
    alist.add("javascript");
    e.put("jlist", alist);
    e.eval("jlist[0] = 'Nashorn'");
    System.out.println(alist.get(1)); // change reflected here

    // Third case - a JSObject array-like object accessed by indexing
    e.put("myObj", new AbstractJSObject() {
        private Map<Integer, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
        @Override
        public void setSlot(int index, Object val) {
            values.put(index, val);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getSlot(int index) {
            return values.get(index);
        }
   });

   e.eval("myObj[0] = 'hello'");
   e.eval("print(myObj[0])");
 }
}
```

Comment: Wow! This is an amazing answer! Thank you :) Works like a charm :)